# Lost all email and accounts in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, email

Open up Thunderbird at system startup and found the wizard to create email?

**There are not any of the accounts I had, no mail whatsoever**

This happens to me very frequently, and thus I consider it one of the "ubuntu morning tax" - a way of qualifing all the problems that ubuntu gives you

Comment: This is a Share knowledge question. I intend to post my own answer.. didn't know askubuntu doesnt allow you to answer it right away

Comment: You seem to imply it's an Ubuntu bug so I hope you filed a proper bug report.

Comment: I have experienced this issue, but not recently and **not** under Ubuntu. *What is your usual method of resolution?* *What do you identify as the root cause?*

Comment: @david6 what system are you using then? doest it happen only at morning startup too? additional to this I have a bunch of folders in conflic in a couple of the accounts

Comment: Can you please add versions for **Ubuntu** and **Thunderbird**.

Comment: @david6 I'm using ubuntu 12.04 thunderbird 16.0.2

Comment: IMHO This sounds more like a storage device failing or accidental deletion than a software problem. If this actually is a software problem I would expect that we would be flooded with "Me too",s in the comment section.

Answer (score 3):

I want to share what I do most of the time: all the solutions I've tried and work can be found [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Recovering_a_profile_that_suddenly_disappeared). Just patiently troubleshoot it. It is most likely a corrupt pref.js file.

**The causes:** to me still unknown, but the last two times I've had this I see that the history in package update includes mysql updates.  Since this happens  at first startup, i assume it is always related to updates.

**Good practices:** I have comed to save a lot of time by doing this:

1) backup the folder where my email is (thunderbird's profile)  [using deja dup + ubuntu one](http://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/). If it is a prefs.js corruption it can be quickly restored, and thunderbird just needs to be restarted.

It can be used to restore email as well.

2) Always keep the profile in some other place that is not the default location. In the same link i provided there is more information about how to do that. This is to avoid thunderbird from "forgetting" your profile and it is easier to backup if you simply locate it with your documents

Hope it helps